# Return ReadableStream from NextJs (express) via chatGpt api stream

Tags: node.js, nestjs, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am very new to nodejs, but playing around with some of the new chatgpt stuff.

I have some code which takes a topic and generates a joke. This is using the streaming version of `https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions`

I can see the stream is coming back a giving each of the parts but the client side is not getting the stream correctly.

The `console.log({done, value});` on the client is only getting hit twice, but the stream when debugging the server has many more chunks than that.

```
// the value decoded here is '{}'
home-page.tsx:46 {done: false, value: Uint8Array(2)} 
home-page.tsx:46 {done: true, value: undefined}
```

What am i missing to wire this stream up properly from the server?

## OpenAPI helper

```
import { createParser, ParsedEvent, ReconnectInterval } from "eventsource-parser";

export const config = {
    runtime: "edge",
};

export async function OpenAIStream(payload) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();

    let counter = 0;

    const res = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });

    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        async start(controller) {
            function onParse(event: ParsedEvent | ReconnectInterval) {
                if (event.type === "event") {
                    const data = event.data;
                    if (data === "[DONE]") {
                        controller.close();
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        const json = JSON.parse(data);
                        const text = json.choices[0].delta?.content || "";
                        if (counter < 2 && (text.match(/\n/) || []).length) {
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log(text);
                        const queue = encoder.encode(text);
                        controller.enqueue(queue);
                        counter++;
                    } catch (e) {
                        controller.error(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            // stream response (SSE) from OpenAI may be fragmented into multiple chunks
            // this ensures we properly read chunks & invoke an event for each SSE event stream
            const parser = createParser(onParse);

            // https://web.dev/streams/#asynchronous-iteration
            for await (const chunk of res.body as any) {
                parser.feed(decoder.decode(chunk));
            }
        },
    });

    return stream;
}
```

## Nest Controller

```
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { OpenAIStream } from './helpers/openai';
import { ChatCompletionRequestMessage } from 'openai';

const MAX_RESPONSE_TOKENS = 200;//1024;

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) { }

  @Post("joke")
  async generate(@Body() message: JokeTemplate) {
    let messages: Array<ChatCompletionRequestMessage> = [
      { "role": "system", "content": "You are a joke engine." },
      { "role": "user", "content": `Tell me a joke about ${message.subject}` }]

    const payload = {
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      max_tokens: MAX_RESPONSE_TOKENS,
      temperature: 0,
      messages,
      stream: true
    };

    const stream = await OpenAIStream(payload);
    return new Response(stream);
  }
}

interface JokeTemplate {
  subject: string;
}
```

## Client button trigger for server

```
const triggerGPTRequest = async (e: any) => {
    setGptResponse('');
    setLoading(true);

    const response = await fetch("/api/joke", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 'subject': promptText }),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }

    const data = response.body;
    if (!data) {
      return;
    }
    const reader = data.getReader();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    let done = false;

    while (!done) {
      const {value, done: doneReading} = await reader.read();
      done = doneReading;
      const chunkValue = decoder.decode(value);
      console.log({done, value});
      setGptResponse((prev) => prev + chunkValue);
    }

    setLoading(false);
  }
```

Comment: What is that `Response` constructor you're using?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response it's this. Just returning the stream is the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Nest doesn't know about fetch's `Response` type, it just sees that type as a class, so it's trying to serialize it which is causing you errors. Try returning a `StreamableFile` instance instead, which Nest will properly handle by calling `stream.pipe(res)`.

```js
import { Body, Controller, Post, StreamableFile } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { OpenAIStream } from './helpers/openai';
import { ChatCompletionRequestMessage } from 'openai';

const MAX_RESPONSE_TOKENS = 200;//1024;

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) { }

  @Post("joke")
  async generate(@Body() message: JokeTemplate) {
    let messages: Array<ChatCompletionRequestMessage> = [
      { "role": "system", "content": "You are a joke engine." },
      { "role": "user", "content": `Tell me a joke about ${message.subject}` }]

    const payload = {
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      max_tokens: MAX_RESPONSE_TOKENS,
      temperature: 0,
      messages,
      stream: true
    };

    const stream = await OpenAIStream(payload);
    return new StreamableFile(stream)
  }
}

interface JokeTemplate {
  subject: string;
}
```

Comment: stream is of type `ReadableStream<any>` and wont go into the `new StreamableFile(stream)`.

Comment: My latest assumption is that I am not running on https, so I am currently trying to configure that to retest. I believe https is required for streaming to be enabled. I am running all of this locally for development.

Comment: Where does that `ReadableStream<any>` type come from? It's _most likely_ fine to `as any` it, but I want to double check

Comment: It comes from the OpenAPI helper in the above code. I tried casting as `any` and it compiled and ran but with the same result.